# How to Completely Close Word application using VB script

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro / script in word that converts docx files into PDF; once the files are converted, I want to just simply close the word application (the macro). The conversion part works well, but the macro still remains open. …How would I go about closing the macro / MS word application once all the files are converted?

The script:

```
Sub BatchConvertDocxToPDF()
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String
 
  'Initialization
  strFolder = "C:\Users\Public\ConvertedFiles\"
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
 
  'Precess each file in the file folder and convert them to pdf.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & strFile)
 
    objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      OutputFileName:=Replace(objDoc.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
      ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
      Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent
 
    objDoc.Close
    strFile = Dir()
  Wend
  
  'close word
  Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  AppWord.Visible = True
  AppWord.Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Comment: Why would you create an additional instance of Word and immediately close that once your conversion is done? Don't you just want to close the current instance?

Comment: The Automation standard says programs should not exit if made visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
Application.Quit
```

Instead of

```
Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
AppWord.Visible = True
AppWord.Application.Quit
```

This bit creates a new instance of Word only to close it immediately, which is completely useless.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance!